# In the figure, prove that points D, M and P are collinear.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The problem is this: by construction draw an exterior equilateral triangle $BCP$ to the square $ABCD$, and an interior equilateral triangle $ABM$.Prove that the points $D$, $M$ and $P$ are collinear.

[image: Figure]

I already figure it out that the angles $\angle PDC=15º$, $\angle DPC=15º$, $\angle BMP=45º$, $\angle MPB=45º$, $\angle MDA=75º$ and $\angle MBP=90º$. And is obvious that triangles $MBP$ and $DCP$ are isosceles. I know that all that somehow justify that the points mentioned are collinear but I dont know how to make the conclution.

Also tried to assume that $M$ is not in between $DP$ but got stuck again trying to find the contradiction.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it a matter of angle chasing?
[image]

Comment: Indeed. I know the messure of all the angles that you have in the picture. I know that is a straight line. But, if I say that is not like I'm using the result that M is already collinear? Because of the way I calculate the angles?

Comment: @Mr.Lu, I edited the picture.

Comment: I feel dumb now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Find $\angle AMD$ from the isosceles triangle MAD instead.

See if $\angle AMD + \angle AMB  + \angle BMP = 180^0$ or not.

Added:

M is a point between P and D. There are only two cases that can happen:- (1) PM and MD form a straight line; or (2) PM and MD together form a crooked V; [but not both].

If $\angle AMD + \angle AMB  + \angle BMP = 180^0$, case (2) is untrue. Then. we are left with case (1) only. The method used above is the  theorem quoted as "adjacent angles supplementary" and is the major method used by Euclide to prove collinearity.

Comment: They are, $\angle AMB=60º$ because of the construction. The triangle is equilateral. And triangle $MBP$ is isosceles, also because of the construction. How can I conclude that $P-M-D$ with $∠AMD+∠AMB+∠BMP=180º$?

Comment: If it is a yes, then DMP is a straight line (i.e. D, M, P are collinear) by the reason of "adjacent angles supplementary".

Comment: Yes, is clear that sum of the angles is 180, I had the exact same conclutions that @Seyed post. But since is a construction, It feels like I'm using what I'm trying to prove? Maybe my english don't let me be clear enough =(. 

Like, I don't have to get complicated doing the same angle chase for lines $MP$ and $MD$, and then say that the lines are the same line therefore collinear?

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. My problem is with how to write the conclusion of the result instead of if I know that the results holds and which are the angles.

Comment: @Mr.Lu  See added.